# How to manage adding and subtracting values based on user input?

Tags: java, math

I have a shopping cart that looks like this:

```
Title    Price    Amount    Total
Item1    20         3        60
Item2    15         2        30


TotalAll:90
```

`Amount` column is input tag where user can put how many items he wants to buy, and everything works as long as the user is adding items since in backend I'm doing sum total`(TotalAll+=Total)`, the problem is when user put a smaller `amount` than currently entered for example for Item1 from 3 to 2 items, TotalAll will still add those 2 and value will be `TotalAll:130` but it should be 70 because it's now 2 items. So how can I subtract from `TotalAll` when `amount` is reduced? In what case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This my solution:

```
        totalAll = 0.0;
        List<Article> articleList = ArticleSelectDAO.selectArticles();
        for (Article a : articleList) {
        totalAll+=a.getTotal();
        }
```

Before i reset `totalAll` i have to update database with current total value per item. Then i add those articles in List, iterate over List and add value to `totalAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever user changes the input, as long as `Total` value is refreshed for that item, You can reset the `TotalAll` value to 0 in your backend wherever you're summing all the `Totals` and recalculate the `TotalAll` value. This may sound inefficient but should work fine if you're dealing with minimal number of items.